# Сместить фон у ссылки при наведении ссылки

Tags: css

подскажите как сместить фон у ссылки на которую наведен курсор, так чтобы не сдвигать сам элемент и не растягивать само меню? Т.е. сам `background` должен уходить за пределы меню вниз, и следовательно пропорционально убирать заливку у элемента сверху. Привожу примерное меню, которое хочу изменить (код не мой, просто для понимания):
[Пример](http://codepen.io/Sonick/pen/xJagi)

Answer (score 2):

css Вам в помощь:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
:hover {
    width: 560px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-image: url(bg-clouds.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

[demo](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-animation-css.php)

Comment: и как это решает проблему? закрасить элемент при наведении и я могу, но меня интересует как сместить эту закраску.

Comment: @Денис подключите фантазию и программирование. Обновил пост. Да вариантов куча. Можете делать анимацию на hover, можете просто сдвинуть фон и получите фон родителя. Нарисуйте что хотите дайте денег программистам они Вам зделают.

Comment: Тут Вы можете воспользоваться фоновой картинкой, например, для которой Вы можете задать координаты смещения. http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/background-position-so-smesheniem

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вроде бы

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a{
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  text-align:center;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:url(http://i.artfile.ru/s/820966_180414_53_ArtFile_ru.jpg);
  background-size:120% 120%;
  color:#fefefe;
  font-size:20px;
  transition:all .5s;
}
a:hover{
  background-position:-10px 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> Главная</a>
```